# createButton - SWT.PUSH versus OK

Tags: java, button, swt

This is my `createButtonsForButtonsBar` Method.

```
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
  Button okButton = createButton(parent, SWT.PUSH, "Close Aplot", true);
  okButton.setEnabled(true);
  okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        viewer = null;
        getShell().setVisible(false);
    }
  });
}
```

I had to change

```
Button okButton = createButton(parent, OK, "Close Aplot", true);
```

to

```
Button okButton = createButton(parent, SWT.PUSH, "Close Aplot", true);
```

Because the OK version was throwing a runtime null pointer error at this line

```
getShell().setVisible(false);
```

Error roughly:

> Unhandled event loop exception java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.test.BaseDialog$7.widgetSelected(BaseDialog.java:277

Question :

What is the difference between `OK` and `SWT.PUSH`?

Why would OK cause the error above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `OK` is a system button ID that indicates certain behavior.  In particular, pressing the `OK` button will close the dialog.  Meanwhile, you had added a button selection listener that *also* tried to close the dialog.  Understandably, this would fail.

What you have done here, however, is to create a button that is not a system default button and has no associated default behavior.  But you've confused `SWT.PUSH` - a style constant - with a button ID.  If you want to provide your own button ID, you need to use an ID greater than `IDialogConstants.CLIENT_ID`.

What you probably want to do here is to simply let the system close your dialog for you, removing your selection listener entirely.  If there's something you want to do when your dialog is closing - say cleaning up some handles - you should simply override `close()`.

Comment: By your answer, I see that my issue is more of a design flaw.  You have answered this question.  I may need to open another question on best practice to hide the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Edward mentioned is right. You are should pass button ID in that method. But, the button style is already `SWT.PUSH` style in `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createButton(Composite, int, String, boolean)`. Please double check. Also you should call/override `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.okPressed()` handle close operation for the dialog. Hope this helps as well.